# Logo and title on same line rather then title below logo

Tags: css

Sorry I am new to coding CSS, but have started with the WP Twenty Sixteen theme which I want to modify such that the site title and logo are aligned such that the logo and title are on the same line with the title centered on the page and the logo on the left. Currently the Title goes directly under the logo. Here is what I think is the correct unmodified 2016 code snippet from the theme?

```
.custom-logo {
    max-width: 180px;
}

.site-title {
    font-family: Montserrat, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-size: 1.4375rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.2173913043;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Ideally I would like to use the additional CSS feature until I get more familiar with modifying themes. I can get the title centered but below the logo and can move the title down (add but not remove vertical whitespace).

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:left;` to float the element to left. Below is the code example:

```css
.custom-logo {
    max-width: 180px;
    float:left;
}

.site-title {
    font-family: Montserrat, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.4375rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.2173913043;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="logotitlewrapper">
  <div class="custom-logo">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/180x100/000/fff&text=dummy+logo+image" />
  </div>
  <div class="site-title">
    <h1>Site Title</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had already tried that but with additional CSS code - not modifying the TwentySixteen theme. It looks as if CSS may act as a single pass compiler. I will hunt up how I edit the theme directly. I get an error (which probably has to do with write access) 
Not Acceptable

An appropriate representation of the requested resource /blog0/wp-admin/theme-editor.php could not be found on this server.

Additionally, a 406 Not Acceptable error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Answer (score 0):

Use display:inline-block; and vertical-align:middle; and paste it in both class just add margin so it will add a space between them.